# How to uninstall packages installed with dpkg

Tags: kali-linux

I've installed steam in my Kali Linux machine with `dpkg`. I want to uninstall steam.

I've already tried uninstalling steam with `dpkg -r steam_latest` and `dpkg --purge steam_latest` but it's giving me error

> dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove steam_latest which isn't
>   installed

Also I've tried uninstalling it with `apt`. Here is the result with `apt`

> Reading package lists... Done    Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Package 'steam:i386' is not
>   installed, so not removed
>   You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken
>   install' to correct these.
>   The following packages have unmet
>   dependencies:    steam-launcher :
>   Depends: python-apt but it is not
>   going to be installed    Recommends: jockey-common but it is not
>   installable
>
> E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: Check if it is installed: sudo apt list --installed | grep steam

Comment: Yes it's showing steam is installed.

Comment: Try: sudo apt-get purge '^steam.*'

Comment: Thank you so much, my problem has been solved. But what is the use of symbols `^` , `.` , `*`. I've already tried uninstalling steam with `apt purge` but I was unable to uninstall it properly.

Comment: the ^ and .* are part of regular expression.  '^steam.*' matches all packages with names starting with 'steam'. I have converted my comment to an answer since it resolved your issue.

Comment: Okay! Thank you so  much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try: `sudo apt-get purge '^steam.*'`

Comment: There are still some files left in the home/user directory. All starting with steam. Kill those mf too.

Comment: Apt / `dpkg` will never touch your home directory. It only installs and removes system-wide packages.

Answer (score -1):

the ^ character is used to match any first  file name or word for the steam
and the * character is used to match any characters can be more than one or zero and the period . character is used to match more than 1 characters